# Electron Forge with React and Typescript gives Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, electron-forge

I'm new to Electron.js and I'm trying to use it to build an app with React and trying to send custom desktop notifications for my app. I have tried a lot of things but been running into this error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 1:11-24 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '<pathToProject>/Desktop/Projects/todo-list/node_modules/electron'.
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 2:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '<pathToProject>/Desktop/Projects/todo-list/node_modules/electron'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

console error:
[image: Console error]

This occurs when I try using the ipcRenderer as follows just to create dynamic notifications as follows:

App.tsx ->

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from "./components/Navbar";
import {ipcRenderer} from "electron";


const App: React.FC = () => {
    const notificationData = {
        notificationTitle: 'Notification Title',
        notificationBody: 'Notification Body'
    }
    return (
        <>
            <NavBar/>
            <h1>Hello there!</h1>
            <button onClick={() => ipcRenderer.send('show-notification', notificationData)}>Click me for notification</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

index.ts

```
import { app, BrowserWindow,ipcMain } from 'electron';
import CreateNotification from "./components/CreateNotification";
// This allows TypeScript to pick up the magic constants that's auto-generated by Forge's Webpack
// plugin that tells the Electron app where to look for the Webpack-bundled app code (depending on
// whether you're running in development or production).
import path from "path";

declare const MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string;
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string;
// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = (): void => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
      nodeIntegration: true
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  ipcMain.on('show-notification', (event, data) => {
    CreateNotification(data);
  });
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

CreateNotification.ts

```
import {Notification} from "electron";

type NotificationData = {
    notificationTitle: string;
    notificationBody: string
}
const CreateNotification = ({notificationTitle, notificationBody}: NotificationData) => {

    new Notification({
        title: notificationTitle,
        body: notificationBody
    }).show()
}

export default CreateNotification;
```

So far are the things I have tried:

- Adding a custom webpack.config.ts
- Adding the follwing in package.json

```
"browser": {
  "fs": false
}
```

- I also tried various preload.ts and tsconfig configuration changes from all the resources of other people running into the same issue but I have had no luck so far. I would greatly appreciate any insights in fixing this error, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get happens when you try to compile NodeJS code with webpack (on an Electron app). For [security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security) reasons, your should not use NodeJS on your renderer process.

To use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) correctly, you should use a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) file to expose what you need, and then use the exposed function on your renderer process:

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  showNotification: (notificationData) => {
    ipcRenderer.send('show-notification', notificationData);
  }
});
```

As a reminder, you should never expose the whole `ipcRenderer` API directly for [security reasons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations).

**App.tsx**

```
const { electronAPI } = window;

[...]

<button onClick={() => electronAPI.showNotification(notificationData)}>
  Click me for notification
</button>
```

And if you care about security, you should also disable `nodeIntegration` on the `webPreferences` of your window:

```
webPreferences: {
  preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
  nodeIntegration: false // This is the default value
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for that! the official Electron docs also have this same explanation I should read it more throughly! https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc